# html type="submit" doesn't work

Tags: html

I am following a tutorial, and now I have this simple code

```
<form>
 <input name=“q”>
 <input type=“submit”>
</form>
```

, this should show a button, but it appears to be a text box. The most weird thing is, I copy paste the exactly same text  to my textedit(cover my original ), and it works fine as a button. However, when I try to delete a letter( such as the t in sumbit) and then retype it, it won't work again.

Comment: Where is your tutorial from?

Comment: @Jack Brandon's answer below will fix the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use smart quotes when writing HTML. It won't get interpreted correctly so it just goes with the default `input` type of of text.

Change

```
<input name=“q”>
<input type=“submit”>
```

to

```
<input name="q">
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: @Jack, no problem. If this answer solved your problem you can mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

Browser did not parse the html because the wrong quotation marks

original

```
<form>
   <input name=“q”>
   <input type=“submit”>
</form>
```

new

```
<form>
  <input name="q">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What is the problem and how does this solve it?